# Switch database server automatically on timeout

Tags: php, postgresql

I have a web application written in PHP which uses PostgreSQL database. The application communicates with two databases, one for application details and other for retrieving and saving institution-wise data. There are two database servers for the second database - master and slave. Normally the application connects to master database. But the client shutdown the local server (master) at night, but they still want to use the application. Is there any way for the application to switch db server automatically whenever the master connection is available?

One way I found is writing the switching logic in the application itself, so that when timeout occurs for master connection, save the status in application database and connect to slave database for upcoming requests. But that requires continuous polling of master database so that the application can connect back when the connection is available.

Comment: Look into load balancers or gateways and redirect traffic from one to the other based on time of day.  I would not recommend doing this in code (PHP) but instead, use an architected approach (i.e. a gateway or load balancer)

Answer (score 2):

Use a libpq connect string like

```
host=primary.my.org,standby.my.org port=5432,5432 dbname=mydb user=myuser
```

That will automatically connect to the standby if the primary is not available. Note that libpq connect strings can be used with any API that links with libpq, which includes the PHP driver.

Comment: I've added multiple hosts for simple fail-over using PDO 
new PDO("pgsql:$host=<ip_address1>,<ip_address2>;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password,array(PDO::ATTR_TIMEOUT => 5)).

It is working in Postgres 9.6 but not in Postgres13. I'm getting the folowing error, 
could not translate host name --- to address: Name or service not known. Any suggestions

Comment: That looks like the IP addresses are (syntactically) bad.